# Flutter: Problem with Google SignIn functions

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am new with Flutter, I am trying to make a screen with flutter SignIn with Google, I have followed docs, everything is good but facing two problems:
I have created a function which tells either the user is SignIn or not or already Signin but having issues with some variable initialization,
Here's my SignIn method which controls the SignIn process:

```
controlSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount) async{
if(signInAccount!= null)  //Over here, its not and error but it says "the operand cannot be null, so the condition is alwqays true"
{
  setState(() {
    isSignedIn=true;
  });
}
else 
{
  setState(() {
    isSignedIn=false;
  });
}

}
```

Next, In order to manage the user:

```
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  gSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((gSigninAccount) {
    controlSignIn(gSigninAccount); 
   }, onError: (gError){
     print("Error:" + gError);
   });
   gSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((gSigninAccount) {
controlSignIn(gSigninAccount);
   }).catchError((gError)
   {
     print("Error:" + gError);
   });
}
```

Here, In this method when I pass the variable "gSigninAccount" to the method "controlSignIn" it says: **The Argument type "GoogleSignInAccount" can't be assigned to parameter type 'GoogleSignInAccount'**